# Java vs C++: Performance in application using web services

Tags: java, c++, performance, web-applications

I'm trying to create a consumer application which gets data from different web services. 
The application has to process real time large volume data. I have to make a choice between Java and C++ only on the basis of performance. Kindly suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Try asking on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In terms of performance both languages are the same. A well written C++ app will be the same speed as a well written Java app. Performance is **NOT** the criteria you should be using to make the decision.

Answer (score 6):

The performance difference for a web site is not as important as the skill set you have available. A well written application in one language will be faster than a not so well written application in the other.

IMHO, you really need to know what you are doing in C++ to write a well written application, in Java its easier to write a well writen program as it doesn't require the same skill level.

I would agree with @Jason's point that you shouldn't consider this a one or the other solution. In a classical application 90% of the time is spent in 10% of the code. Even if you find that C++ is much faster youonly need to do this for 10% of the code.

However, I suspect you are better off spending time looking at the hardware and network infrastructure as these can make more difference and are too easily overlooked by developers.

Comment: This is true in theory. In practice, there is [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) vs. commercial/expensive/flashy/sugar-coated Java based equivalents. Same thing about .NET studio vs. the legacy VC++ 6. In theory, there is no justification for such sluggishness & inefficiency. Yet, in practice & the real world, it exists.

Comment: There is some rubbish commerial technology out there. ;)

Comment: In Java, I developed an exchange which supported persistence of all in bound and out bound messages with a sustained throughput of one million request/events per second and a typical round trip latency of less than one micro-second between processes on the same machine.  In C++, I might have been able to make it faster, but did I really need to? ;)

Comment: Was it build from scratch? If not, which framework did you use?

Comment: Built from scratch. After I left, I wrote an open source library for low latency queueing/logging/messaging https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle (nothing like an exchange ;)

Comment: Ah. That explains it. :) Kudos for the accomplishment.

Comment: @Daniel Cheers, needless to say, I haven't found a use case where it is used to it's limit, though it is useful. There was only 900 million equity trades in 2008 (more orders of course), at one million per second that is 15 minutes ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your scenario involves a bottleneck due to network bandwidth, it probably doesn't matter what language you use as long as it handles I/O efficiently. Both Java and C++ do this fine.

If your scenario involves a bottleneck due to computational bandwidth, C++ might be more efficient. Java has become fairly efficient in recent years through JIT compilation and other techniques.

If I were doing this myself, I prefer Java to C++ because it is a higher-level language with better tools and less opportunities for errors via memory management. I would prototype the computational part of the system in Java, and see how it performs. If adequate, I would stay in Java. Otherwise I'd compare with C++, possibly using JNI or JNA to execute the high-performance computation in C++ if there were performance benefits.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually possible to write software in C++ that processes data more efficiently than equivalent software written in Java. The difference is often marginal.

Since C++ is complex it is quite common that novice programmers write C++ that performs very weakly. Java is simpler, so it is hard to make so big mistakes in Java.